# Passing powershell multiple arguments in C# using Process.Start

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application, process.start

I'm calling a PowerShell script from a console app. I need to call a script in a network share and pass a couple of arguments. I need help constructing the Arguments. I've tried precising the argument with an @ symbol. here is a snipe of the code:

```
 Process process = new Process();
        // Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Noninteractive -File "\\Share\ConfigScript.ps1" -Config "\\Share\Config.xml" -Webservice "https://companysite.net/ConfigSite"";
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

I get multiple CS1002 and CS1056 errors if I jusc copy/paste arguments the way they work in PowerShell.

EDIT: NOTE: powershell.exe in the argument is used to bypass Execution Policy

Comment: Obviously you have a syntax problem, At best you will need to escape this and use a verbatim string

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: also `process.StartInfo.Arguments` should contain only **arguments** (remove `powershell.exe`)

Comment: var escapedString = @"mystring"; is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters in the string.

\\ will give you \

\" will give you "

Note these special characters are escaped using the \ character.  Also, check if you intentionally meant to have powershell.exe in the arguments since it is already specified as the filename?

Comment: powershell.exe in the argument is used to bypass Execution Policy

Comment: ok. then as noted, proceed to escape your string correctly according to the c# specification.